# Unexpected result with integrer

Tags: c, int

My program does convert a int in a litteral number.
It is accurately working with numbers greater than (-9999) or numbers less than 9999 but whenever i type 12314115151 as the users input the program prints a "negative one". I think i did an error in my code and need your help..

Here my code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

void positive(int input, int t);
void negative(int input, int t);

void main(){

int input,t;

clrscr();

textcolor(YELLOW);

cprintf("ENTER YOUR NUMBER: ");

scanf("%i",&input);

    if (input < -9999 || input > 9999){

        textcolor(RED);

        cprintf("\nINVALID ENTRY, PROGRAM TERMINATED");


    }      


    else if(input == 0){

      cprintf("\nNUMBER IN WORD(S): ");

      printf("Zero");

     } 

    else if(input < 0 || input >-10000){

      cprintf("\nNUMBER IN WORD(S): ");

      negative(input,t);
    }
    else if(input > 0 || input <10000){

      cprintf("\nNUMBER IN WORD(S): ");

      positive(input,t);
    }

getch();
}

void positive(int input, int t){

      char* a[11]={"","One","Two","Three","Four","Five","Six","Seven","Eeight","Nine","Ten"};


      char* b[10]={"","Eleven","Twelve","Thirteen","Fourteen","Fifteen","Sixteen","Seventeen","Eighteen","Nineteen"};


      char* c[10]={"","","Twenty","Thirty","Fourty","Fifty","Sixty","Seventy","Eighty","Ninety"};

      textcolor(WHITE);

      if(input > 0 || input < 11){

        t=input/1;
        cprintf("Positive %s",a[t]);
      }

      if(input > 10 || input < 20){

        t=input%10;

        cprintf("Positive %s",b[t]);
      }

      if (input > 19 || input < 100){
        t = input/10;

        cprintf("Positive %s",c[t]);

        t=input%10;

        cprintf(" %s",a[t]);
      }

      if (input > 99 || input < 1000){
        t =input/100;

        cprintf("Positive %s Hundred",a[t]);

        t*=100;
        input-=t;

          if(input > -1 || input < 11){

           t=input/1;
           cprintf(" and %s",a[t]);
          }

          if(input > 10  || input < 20){

            t=input%10;

            cprintf(" and %s",b[t]);
          }

          if (input > 19 || input < 100)
          {
            t=input/10;

            cprintf(" and %s",c[t]);

            input=input%10;

            cprintf(" %s",a[input]);
          }

      }
          if(input >999 || input <10000){
          t=input/1000;

            cprintf("Positive %s Thousand",a[t]);

          t*=1000;
          input-=t;

               if(input > -1 || input < 11){

                t=input/1;
                cprintf(" and %s",a[t]);

              }

              if(input > 10  || input < 20){
                t=input%10;
                cprintf(" and %s",b[t]);
              }

              if (input > 19 || input < 100)
              {
                t=input/10;
                cprintf(" and %s",c[t]);
                input=input%10;
                cprintf(" %s",a[input]);
              }
             if(input > 99 || input < 1000){
                t=input/100;
                  cprintf(" %s Hundred",a[t]);

                 t*=100;
                 input-=t;

                if(input > -1 || input < 11){

                  t=input/1;
                  cprintf(" and %s",a[t]);
                }

                if(input > 10  || input < 20){
                  t=input%10;
                    cprintf(" and %s",b[t]);
                }

                if (input > 19 || input < 100)
                {
                 t=input/10;
                     cprintf(" and %s",c[t]);
                   input=input%10;
                   cprintf(" %s",a[input]);
                  }

             }
          }

    return;
}



void negative(int input, int t){

  char* a[11]={"","One","Two","Three","Four","Five","Six","Seven","Eeight","Nine","Ten"};


  char* b[10]={"","Eleven","Twelve","Thirteen","Fourteen","Fifteen","Sixteen","Seventeen","Eighteen","Nineteen"};


  char* c[10]={"","","Twenty","Thirty","Fourty","Fifty","Sixty","Seventy","Eighty","Ninety"};

  textcolor(WHITE);

  input*=-1; 

  if(input > 0 || input < 11){

    t=input/1;
    cprintf("Negative|| %s",a[t]);
  }

  if(input > 10 || input < 20){

  t=input%10;

  cprintf("Negative %s",b[t]);
  }

  if (input > 19 || input < 100){

  t = input/10;

  cprintf("Negative %s",c[t]);

  t=input%10;

  cprintf(" %s",a[t]);
  }

  if (input > 99 || input < 1000){

  t =input/100;

  cprintf("Negative %s Hundred",a[t]);

  t*=100;
  input-=t;

    if(input > -1 || input < 11){
       t=input/1;
       cprintf(" and %s",a[t]);
    }

    if(input > 10  || input < 20){
      t=input%10;
      cprintf(" and %s",b[t]);
    }

    if (input > 19 || input < 100)
    {
      t=input/10;
      cprintf(" and %s",c[t]);
      input=input%10;
      cprintf(" %s",a[input]);
    }

  }

  if(input >999 || input <10000){
  t=input/1000;
    cprintf("Negative %s Thousand",a[t]);
  t*=1000;
  input-=t;

       if(input > -1 || input < 11){

         t=input/1;
         cprintf(" and %s",a[t]);
      }

      if(input > 10  || input < 20){
        t=input%10;
        cprintf(" and %s",b[t]);
      }

      if (input > 19 || input < 100)
      {
        t=input/10;
        cprintf(" and %s",c[t]);
        input=input%10;
        cprintf(" %s",a[input]);
      }
     if(input > 99 || input < 1000){
      t=input/100;

      cprintf(" %s Hundred",a[t]);

      t*=100;
      input-=t;

        if(input > -1 || input < 11){

          t=input/1;
          cprintf(" and %s",a[t]);
        }

        if(input > 10  || input < 20){
          t=input%10;
          cprintf(" and %s",b[t]);
        }

        if (input > 19 || input < 100)
        {
         t=input/10;
           cprintf(" and %s",c[t]);
           input=input%10;
           cprintf(" %s",a[input]);
          }

     }
  }

  return;
}
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: `12314115151` is not a valid 32-bit `int` value.

Comment: That's a massive repetition (or near repetition) in the positive and negative code.  You should devise a method to avoid that repetition, probably by printing the string "Negative" and the calling the 'positive' function with the absolute value of the number. That reduces your code magnificently. Further algorithmic changes are needed to make it work with bigger numbers, but once you've got 0..999 covered, the rest is a matter of repetition again with different multipliers, etc.  For example, ten and ten thousand are related, as is ten thousand and ten (or ten thousand ten if you're American).

Answer (score 1):

```
else if(input == 0){

      cprintf("\nNUMBER IN WORD(S): ");

      printf("Zero");

     } 

    else if(input < 0 || input >-10000){ // There should be && instead of ||.

      cprintf("\nNUMBER IN WORD(S): ");

      negative(input,t);
    }
    else if(input > 0 || input <10000){ //There too.

      cprintf("\nNUMBER IN WORD(S): ");

      positive(input,t);
    }
```

As you see I've commented which parts of your code you should edit. Now you are looking of number that is **GREATER THAN -10000** - your number **IS** greater. num<0 doesn't mean anything because it's **OPTIONAL** condition now. And like mentioned down,

> 12314115151 is not a valid 32-bit int value

Answer (score 0):

if you change your condition as bellow you will get desired result:

```
else if(input < 0){

      cprintf("\nNUMBER IN WORD(S): ");

      negative(input,t);
    }
    else if(input > 0){

      cprintf("\nNUMBER IN WORD(S): ");

      positive(input,t);
    }
```